# Flutter MVVM Design pattern for developing app with ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, dart, mvvm

I'm new to flutter. I would like to create an app in flutter using the MVVM design pattern. I have3 screens and need 3 ViewModel also.

Screen 1 is for login & its ViewModel is LoginViewModel.
Screen 2 is for Listing all data's and Screen 3 is for adding data.

main.dart

```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    
      home: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<LoginViewModel>(create: (_) => LoginViewModel()),
           ChangeNotifierProvider<DataViewModel>(create: (_) => DataViewModel()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider<AddViewModel>(create: (_) => AddViewModel()),
        ],
        child: SplashScreenOne(),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

login.dart

```
    class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoginScreenState();
  }

}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen>{


  TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Size size; // calculate screen size

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

     final vm = Provider.of<LoginViewModel>(context);

    size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return _loginScreen();
  }
```

when I run my app it shows the following error:

[image]

How can I add ChangeNotifier for different screens based on their  ViewModels?